# Disable Application Insights sampling with the ASP.NET Core libraries

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, azure-application-insights

I need to retain all telemetry since we use this for analytics.

According to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-sampling/) I can run the following Analytics query to determine the rate of sampling:

```
requests 
 | where timestamp > ago(1d)
 | summarize 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h) 
 | render areachart
```

The results indicate some heavily sampling, especially during the day where only around 1 in 10 items are retained:

[image: Sampling]

What confuses me is that the Azure Portal insdicates that sampling is set to 100%:

[image: Azure Portal Insights]

Perhaps this only reflects Ingestion sampling? Adaptive sampling could still be occurring on the server.

**How do I disable sampling completely using the ASP.NET Core libraries for Application Insights?** (i.e. Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 1.0.2)

Currently, this is these are the only configuration I can find and there isn't anything on sampling:

```
var appInsightsConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddApplicationInsightsSettings(
        developerMode: false,
        instrumentationKey: Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"])
    .Build();

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(appInsightsConfiguration);
```

Comment: For non-ASP.NET apps such as worker roles, sampling might be enabled in the ApplicationInsights.config. I had the following element in there:     <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
      <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
    </Add>

Comment: In the sampling document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling it clearly states "Ingestion sampling doesn't operate while adaptive or fixed-rate sampling is in operation", and since adaptive sampling is by default enabled in .net core app, that's why even the Azure Portal indicates the ingestion sampling is set to 100% but it's being ignored

Comment: In the same document, it also state:
The value shown on the portal tile indicates the value that you set for ingestion sampling. It doesn't represent the actual sampling rate if any sort of SDK sampling (adaptive or fixed-rate sampling) is in operation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable sampling by using the [ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/56dc5297134406d6b028076aa5b3582311412e74/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions.cs) class.

A usage example:

```
var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration, aiOptions);
```

See more details about sampling in the [Application Insights ASP.NET Core Github documentation page](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Telemetry-Processors:-Sampling-and-Metrics-Stream).

Hope this  helps,

Asaf

Comment: 12 factor application rule #3 states: "Store config in the environment". The solution to alter environment must not be from application code. I read the manuals, I saw people commenting to use 'MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond', but there seems to be no concrete examples on how to configure sampling via configuration.

Comment: @Asaf Strassberg, I am using Core 2.1, Application insights-2.13.1 and did the same but Sampling isn't disblled, https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1808